# Misbehavior with istringstream conversions

Tags: c++, sstream

When I try to extract valid numbers from an input using `istringstream` I get the follwoing misbehavior from `istringstream`:

**For Example:**

```
void extract(void)
{
double x;
string line, temp;

getline(cin, line);
istringstream is(line);
while(is >>temp)
{
    if(istringstream(temp) >>x)
        {std::cout<<"number read: "<<x<<endl;}
}
```

}

**Input:**
`1 2 3rd 4th`

**Output:**

```
number read: 1
number read: 2
number read: 3
number read: 4
```

The misbehavior is istringstream converting the string `3rd` to the number 3. 
Why does `istringstream` do this and how can one avoid this?

Comment: You're reading a `double` from the stream, not strings.

Comment: @LordZsolt can you please explain more, I'm still confused. Also the same thing happens when I use `atof()`

Comment: @Andy `atof` is broken; it provides no means of error checking.  If you use `strtod`, you can recover the address of the first character not processed; if that isn't `'\0'`, you haven't processed all of the text.

Comment: If you want the input as a string, then the inner `if` statement is not needed. In fact the expression used as the condition in the `if` statement will not work as you expect, because it will extract only the number-part of a string that begins with a number bot doesn't end with a string. If you need to distinguish between pure numbers or strings like `"3rd"` then you need to use e.g. [`std::stod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) which can check if the whole string was converted to a number or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>It's because you read *numbers* from the stream.</strike>

The `>>` operator extracts `"3rd"` from the stream, and tries to convert it to a `double`, but since only the first character of the string is a number, it can only parse the `"3"` and simply discard the non-digit characters.

If you want `"3rd"` then you need to read it as a string.

Comment: What if I want to throw an `invalid_argument` error if the input has something like `3rd`, how would I preceded on doing that knowing the fact you stated above? @JoachimPileborg

Comment: @Andy You might want to read e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get) on how the extraction actually happens. The problem is that the extracted string *begins* with a digit, and since that can be parsed as a number the stream will not have its `failbit` set.

Comment: This is wrong (or I've misunderstood it).  When inputting to a `doubled`, the `>>` does _not_ extract `"3rd"`, it will only extract the `3`.  The `"rd"` will remain in the stream, available for further reads.

Answer (score 0):

The `>>` operators only read as much as they can in the stream,
leaving any remaining characters.  Thus:

```
std::istringstream( temp ) >> x
```

will only extract the `3` if `temp` contains `3rd`, leaving the
`rd`.  In order to ensure that the entire field has been read,
you need to ensure that you are at the end:

```
std::istringstream fieldParser( temp );
if ( fieldParser >> x && fieldParser.peek() == EOF ) {
    // ...
}
```

for example.  (More generally, you'll want to append a `>> std::ws`
to the end of the input chain, to skip any trailing white space.
In your case, however, since you get `temp` using the `>>`
operator, you're guaranteed that it contains no white space.)

FWIW: in this particualar case, I'd use `strtod`:

```
errno = 0;
const char* end;
x = strtod( temp.c_str(), &end );
if ( errno != 0 || *end != '\0' ) {
    //  Error occured...
}
```

Either way, however, you can't do it in a single `if`; you'll
need extra code before.